# cannot install the best candidate for the job - nothing provides system-logos(httpd-logo-ng) needed by httpd-2.4.37-43 centos stream 8

Tags: centos8

When trying to install apache, I continually receive the error:

Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
-nothing provides system-logos(httpd-logo-ng) needed by httpd-2.4.37-43

Thanks.

tried:

-sudo dnf clean all
-sudo rm -r /var/chace/dnf
-installing the package httpd-logo-ng via direct rpm

Nothing seems to work.